# Webform submission value token not working

Tags: webform-civicrm, tokens

From a webform submission I would like to send an automated email, for example with first name. As per webform token I have included Dear  [submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_first_name:nolabel] within the body of the email.

But unfortunately result returns empty. Anyone experienced issues like this? any tips please?

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it simply prints the token code "[submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_fieldset_fieldset:civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_first_name]". And not the actual values. Any ideas what the issue might be. I have following installation:
core = 7.x
Webform 7.x-3.18
Webform Conditional 7.x-1.0-beta2
Webform Layout 7.x-1.0 Webform Report 7.x-1.0
Webform Tokens 7.x-1.6
Webform CiviCRM Integration 3.5
Webform Conditional 1.0-beta2
Webform Layout 1.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tapash, I've just tested this myself and I've had success with including the fieldset within the token so that it looks something like the following:

[submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_fieldset_fieldset:civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_first_name]

You'll want to update the above if you've customised any of the keys or are using a different contact!

Comment: You would be right, if the field is still in the fieldset and hopefully that is the issue for Tapash. But if the fieldset has been done away with, the token in the Q seems correct.

Comment: Has anyone tried using this with Contact 2 and Contact 3? I am getting a blank result when using the token with Contact 2 and Contact 3 but works fine with Contact 1.

Comment: My bad. There was a fieldset within a fieldset. Works fine for contact 2 and contact 3 as well.

Comment: This makes perfect sense but it is ridiculous that I could never have worked this out from the docs: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/backdrop/webform/